# How to install CKEDITOR to angular project and add plugins

Tags: angular, ckeditor, editor, wiris

I am trying to install ckeditor to my angular project. I already tried installing `ckeditor4-angular` via npm but was unable to find a way to add plugins like the WIRIS mathType. Please how can i install the editor to my angular project and as well install plugins?

Comment: use CKEditor in angular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155972/how-to-get-data-from-ckeditor/58156538#58156538

Comment: add a plugin to CKEditor in angular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39208766/ng2-ckeditor-add-placeholder-plugin-using-typescript-and-angular-2-0/64329399#64329399

Answer (score 19):

Here is an issue regarding this https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/issues/134. You need to create your custom CKEditor build and include necessary plugins into it. Here is the guide: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/development/custom-builds.html
BTW I suggest you to use CKEditor 5, the latest version.

UPD:

1. Clone the original repo:

`git clone https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic.git`

2. Install dependencies

`npm install`

3. Install necessary plugin itself

`npm install --save @wiris/mathtype-ckeditor5`

4. Open `src/ckeditor.js` and new plugin to the editor:

```
...
import MathType from '@wiris/mathtype-ckeditor5';
...

ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins = [
   ...
   MathType
];

ClassicEditor.defaultConfig = {
    toolbar: {
        items: [
            ...
            'MathType',
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
};
```

5. Then build the editor (you maybe need to install yarn)

`yarn run build`

6. After that copy everything from `build` folder to your project. For instance

```
src/assets/js/ck-editor-math-type/
   -> translations
      -> ...
   -> ckeditor.js
```

7. Add ckeditor code to `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.1.2",
   ...
}
```

8. Import CKEditor to your component:

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '../../assets/js/ck-editor-math-type/ckeditor.js';

...
export class CkeditComponent implements OnInit {

    public Editor = ClassicEditor;

    public model = {
        editorData: '<p>Hello, world!</p>'
    };
}
```

9. Add it too your template.html

```
<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="model.editorData" [editor]="Editor"></ckeditor>
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Okay. I will love to see the steps as you progress.

Comment: I am getting duplicate module error, exactly followed the procedure.

Comment: In case anybody wants to use it as an `npm` package, push it up to your github repository ( gitusername/gitbranch ) (on github.com) and use it in package.json as `... "gitbranch": "gitusername/gitbranch#commit-id", ... `. Commit is to ensure you always have the same version. Hope this helps.

Comment: after 7th step do i need to import Ckeditor module in my feature module

Comment: Here is the elaborated step #7 https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html

Comment: I had to set "strict": false in tsconfig.json. If someone has a better solution to solve error 'Could not find a declaration file for module' let me know!

Comment: when copying it to the project you're adding it too - where in the project do you add it? in the node_modules? which package?

Answer (score 3):

After step 7

Add ckeditor code to package.json
"dependencies": {
...
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.1.2",
...
}

Step 8:

npm install

step 9:

In app.module.ts file you can add

```
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CKEditorModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

step 10:
In file tsconfig.json  add allowJs: ture

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
}
```

step 11:

Import CKEditor to your component:

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '../../assets/js/ck-editor-math-type/ckeditor.js';

...
export class CkeditComponent implements OnInit {

    public Editor = ClassicEditor;

    public model = {
        editorData: '<p>Hello, world!</p>'
    };
}
```

step 12:

Add it too your template.html

```
<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="model.editorData" [editor]="Editor"></ckeditor>
```

Comment: Spent the whole day on this trying various resources all over the internet and could not get it to work.

Comment: i have done if you want you can access through this url https://github.com/sarveshhome/ckeditorwithMathPhysics

Comment: For anyone still having issues, ensure your target in your tsconfig.json is `es2015` or higher `"target": "es2015"`

Answer (score 1):

Following steps worked for me :

1. Copy the everything from "ckeditor5\build" folder to your assets folder.
2. Import the module in your app.module.ts file like -

```
//app.module.ts file
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
...
imports:[..., CKEditorModule,]
...
```

3. Now, in your component import the custom ckeditor  like this -

> import * as CustomEditor from '../../../assets/ckeditor.js';

4. Create the object of editor like this

> public Editor = CustomEditor.**Editor**;

**Yes, you have to use Editor property from CustomEditor object**

5. Setup the ckeditor toolbar by settings its **config** property like :

> <ckeditor **[config]="{ toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold'. . . . ] }"** [editor]="Editor">

Please make sure to set config property as it is going to complain if you don't.